# User name missing in mobile version of askubuntu (I think!)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface

I'm pretty sure that your user name used to display when you were logged in and using the mobile version of the site, but now it appears to be missing. I've included a screenshot where I was using Opera Mobile browser (though it is the same on my stock Android browser, Firefox Mobile, and when you use the mobile version in a normal desktop browser.

The screenshot is showing a fingerpress and the empty part of the selected area (to the right of the avatar) is where I'm sure the username used to appear. Could be wrong of course!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It does not also checking the mobile site with Firefox

[image]

Only the avatar and badges, clicking on the avatar or badges will take you to your user profile.

Think this is by design (could be wrong tough).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue in the current build of our network sites. The layout for mobile has also changed considerably in the last 2 years. If you experience further issues please do not hesitate to report bugs.